# Move data from Sharepoint through a Logic App

Tags: sharepoint, triggers, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

We are using Logic App to move data from a Sharepoint folder to an Azure Blob Storage.

We were using the Sharepoint trigger "When a file is created or modified in a folder". Unfortunately, this trigger has been deprecated and does not work anymore (i.e., when a file is indeed created or modified, no further action is done after running the trigger).

No file is moved around anymore. The trigger does not execute the Logic App even though a file is created or modified in the Sharepoint origin folder. I have been through the various other Sharepoint triggers but they do not seem to fit our use case. We cannot create a Logic App for each file. We are not using Sharepoint lists but classic folders. We could use several triggers pointing directly at each existin file, but as we have many files to move in the same folder, we would have to create many Logic Apps and that is not how we want to do it. Moreover, some new files may be created in the future.

What could we do to keep the same architecture of moving data around from Sharepoint to Blob Storage through the non-deprecated Logic App triggers?

Thank you in advance,
Alexis

Comment: You could try to use the File System trigger "When a file is added or modified"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `When a file is created or modified (properties only)` and get the properties of the file that is getting created or updated. Then you can use `Get file content` using the properties from the previous step. Finally, you can create a blob using the previous steps. Below is the flow of my logic app.

[image]

*RESULTS:*

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is what I have been using in the end. The only minor issue is that I cannot specified a library other than "Documents" in the trigger "When the file is created or modified". I have then added a condition afterwards, so the workflow carries on if and only if a file has been modified in a certain folder. Thank you for your answer!